# How to check if all elements of a list are equal or no?

Tags: algorithm

*Without providing code* , I would like to know how can I check if all elements of a list are equals or no.

Thank you.

Comment: use [lists:all/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#all-2). Predicate write yourself.

Comment: btw, search and understanding or  development of algorithm ,from education point, is more helpful part than write code.

Comment: Pick one and compare it to all the others? I'm not sure what the difficulty is here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a list of objects and you want to see if *all* elements are equal then you only need compare the first element to the rest.  Take the first element out and assign it to a variable.  Loop through the remaining list and compare this object with the iterated value.  If at any time this check fails return a boolean false, otherwise return true.

That is an easy way, without code, as you've requested.

Comment: Meh, I was just finishing typing up the same thing when someone came into my office to ask me about something and then you posted. :P Only thing I'd add is that it's got to be O(n), if the OP cares.

Comment: :)  That happens to me all the time on here